# Is it possible to hire a tour guy through Iraq with a film crew for a documentary film on Iraq ancient history?

Tags: safety, tours, guides, middle-east, iraq

We have three people working on a film in Iraq.

We would like to do it with a guide.

We have 2 cameras for est. $6000 each, which is a safety concern.

We plan to make shots in bigger cities but also we would like to visit some ruins like Ur or Babylon etc.

Is it possible to hire some "tour" guide in Baghdad and travel safely with them?

Or hiring such a person is not possible in Iraq?

We would be travelling only during the day, never at night.

Comment: Hi.  As you've been a member for 6 months, you've probably seen the [faq].  As such, you'll be aware each post should contain one question. if you have multiple questions, please ask them separately.  In addition, asking for 'your opinion' is polling, which is also against the rules in the [faq].  As such I'm closing the question, and when you edit it to meet the requirements, please flag it for reopening - it's an interesting topic and mission, but needs to follow the rules.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, I have changed the question to meet the rules. Please, reopen it, thank you in advance.

Comment: Next time, please use the 'reopen' button, otherwise I might miss it - it notifies all mods.  Reopening now

Comment: Edited the wording to make it a bit clearer, hope that's ok.

Comment: Thank you a lot for reordering the words. I am not a native English speaker so I make a lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You will be able to find someone. You must contact the local authorities first for permission and they will be able to help you.  If you are planning for any tour or traveling somewhere you can take idea from traveling site like koshertravelers site. It will give you good deals about traveling.